# Xtext content/template proposal

Tags: xtext

Another Xtext question! My goal would be to create a template/content proposal for an annotation-like structure, which looks like this:

```
Model:
    elements+=Element*;

Element:
    AnnotationDecl | ClassDecl;

AnnotationDecl:
    'annotation' name=ID '{' fields+=AnnotationDeclField* '}';

AnnotationDeclField:
    name=ID;

Annotation:
    '@' declaration=[AnnotationDecl] '(' members+=AnnotationField* ')';

AnnotationField:
    declaration=[AnnotationDeclField] '=' value=STRING;

ClassDecl:
    annotations+=Annotation* 'class' name=ID '{' /* ... */ '}';
```

And a sample usage of this language would be something like this:

```
annotation Foo { 
    foo 
    bar
} 

@Foo(foo = 'foo' bar = 'bar')
class A { 
}
```

### The problem

Now in the current state, if i write the necessary scope provider, Xtext provides a pretty good base for the user for completing this structure, but if he/she is not familiar with the structure of the language, it might be confusing to type the following:

`@` <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> Select `Foo` <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> select `(` <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> ...

So my idea would be to provide a pre-filled base, which is syntactically correct, and he/she only has to fill the important parts using the navigation with <kbd>tab</kbd> in a template:

```
@Foo(foo = '${foo}' bar = '${bar}')
```

### Attempts to solve this:

I have made 2 attempts to do this, none of them was quite what i'm looking for.

### 1. Content proposal

The first is solving this with content proposals like this:

```
class MyDslProposalProvider extends AbstractMyDslProposalProvider {

    override complete_Annotation(EObject model, RuleCall rc, ContentAssistContext ctx, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
        super.complete_Annotation(model, rc, ctx, acceptor)
        if (model == null || model.eContainer == null) {
            return
        }
        val rootModel = model.eContainer as Model
        val annotationDecls = rootModel.elements.filter(AnnotationDecl)
        annotationDecls.forEach [ annDecl |
            val fieldsProposals = annDecl.fields.map[name].map[field|'''«field» = ${«field»}''']
            val fullProposalText = '''@«annDecl.name»(«fieldsProposals.join(' ')»)'''
            val proposal = createCompletionProposal(fullProposalText, annDecl.name, null, ctx)
            acceptor.accept(proposal)
        ]
    }
}
```

Which gets the context right, because it shows the proposal right after I type the `@` character, but because its not a template, it will be used as-is and display the original String what was created:

```
@Foo(foo = '${foo}' bar = '${bar}')
```

### 2. Template proposal

My second attempt was to create a template proposal provider, which looked like this:

```
class MyDslTemplateProposalProvider extends DefaultTemplateProposalProvider {

    @Inject
    new(TemplateStore templateStore, ContextTypeRegistry registry, ContextTypeIdHelper helper) {
        super(templateStore, registry, helper)
    }

    override protected createTemplates(TemplateContext tplCtx, ContentAssistContext ctx, ITemplateAcceptor acceptor) {
        super.createTemplates(tplCtx, ctx, acceptor)
        val rootModel = ctx.rootModel as Model
        if (rootModel == null) {
            return
        }
        val annotationDecls = rootModel.elements.filter(AnnotationDecl)
        annotationDecls.forEach [ annDecl |
            val fieldsProposals = annDecl.fields.map[name].map[field|'''«field» = '${«field»}' '''.toString.trim]
            val fullProposalText = '''@«annDecl.name»(«fieldsProposals.join(' ')»)'''
            val template = new Template(annDecl.name, '', annDecl.name, fullProposalText, true)
            val proposal = createProposal(template, tplCtx, ctx, null, getRelevance(template))
            acceptor.accept(proposal)
        ]
    }
}
```

Which created exactly what i wanted in terms of content, but I couldn't fine-tune it, so it only shows after I type the `'@'` character and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> (like the content proposal), because it looks like it won't show if I'm in the middle of an unfinished rule.

### So my question:

**Which would be the right solution?**

- Is the regular content proposal configurable somehow, so it's
  interpreted as a template?
- Or can I somehow fine tune the template
  proposal to only show in the context I want it to show (`@` pressed)?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the lots of code, I really tried to narrow it down to the relevant parts!

Answer (score 0):

the createTemplates method gives you access to the ContentAssistContext and thus to the getCurrentNode from which you may determine if there is already an @

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the help. I managed to find out from the `ContentAssistContext` where the proposal should be shown, but it doesn't show up. When I check with a simple `if(ctx.prefix == '@'){/* add it */}` the `createProposal()` method fails to validate the template with the current context (don't know why) and returns `null`. Do you have an idea, why this could happen?

Comment: no i have no idea. you should debug on that. maybe the template should include the prefix

Comment: Tried both way, no luck. I didn't really want to debug the framework code, because the call stack was really long, but do you know what the validation before the adding the template proposal should do? I'm sure, it doesn't run the whole validation, that is running on save, because in other places (where the `@` prefix is not present) it lets me add syntactically incorrect stuff too.

Comment: sorry i have no idea on this. i dont know the internals of xtext in this part